# Are there applications of quandles in quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics, topology

I have learned from a knot theorist that [quandles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) were developed in order to more sensitively distinguish between distinct knots. However, they seem to be an interesting algebraic object in themselves.

Are there any applications of quandles to quantum theory?

Comment: A Google search for “arxiv physics quandle” finds no physics preprints.

Comment: You may have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603085v2 and http://tgdtheory.com/pdfpool/knotstgd.pdf